# libvpx KeyError for webrtc

Tags: python, webrtc, libvpx

i am generating project of webrtc using gyp & while generating things, i got following error:

> File "/home/rtcdev/Nishant/src/webrtc/build/gyp_webrtc", line 102, in
>   
>       gyp_rc = gyp.main(args)   File "/home/rtcdev/Nishant/src/tools/gyp/pylib/gyp/**init**.py", line 526,
>   in main
>       return gyp_main(args)   File "/home/rtcdev/Nishant/src/tools/gyp/pylib/gyp/**init**.py", line 502,
>   in gyp_main
>       params, options.check, options.circular_check)   File "/home/rtcdev/Nishant/src/tools/gyp/pylib/gyp/**init**.py", line 129,
>   in Load
>       params['parallel'], params['root_targets'])   File "/home/rtcdev/Nishant/src/tools/gyp/pylib/gyp/input.py", line 2756, in
>   Load
>       RemoveLinkDependenciesFromNoneTargets(targets)   File "/home/rtcdev/Nishant/src/tools/gyp/pylib/gyp/input.py", line 1501, in
>   RemoveLinkDependenciesFromNoneTargets
>       if targets[t].get('variables', {}).get('link_dependency', 0): KeyError: 'third_party/libvpx/libvpx.gyp:libvpx_obj_int_extract#host'

**Question:**

i am not getting what this error want to tell as well as How to overcome from this error?

Comment: probably `t` is not in `targets` in file /gyp/pylib/gyp/input.py", line 1501

Comment: @RickyA where to define **targets**? can you please guide me.. i am stuck here..

Comment: Well that is about the most useful thing I can say from the information you have given me.

Comment: can we go for chat, as i need some suggetion for python?